# Deciding whether CFG generates the empty word

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Give an algorithm to decide the following problem: given
a CFG $G$, does $G\Rightarrow^\star \epsilon$? That is, given a grammar can it
generate the empty word? How can I make sure my algorithm is decidable?

Comment: Convert your grammar to Chomsky normal form.

Comment: There are also simpler algorithms, which iteratively construct the set of nonterminals which can generate the empty word. Such algorithms come up when converting to CNF.